# Flink Stuck on Broadcast

Tags: java, serialization, apache-flink, kryo

I encountered a problem where Flink gets stuck during broadcast state writing on:

```
ctx.collect(data）
```

where ctx is SourceContext

there is no exception thrown and the the tread dump is stuck around, but is running and not stuck:

```
"Legacy Source Thread - Source: deviceInfoReader (1/1)#0" Id=86 RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.flink.core.memory.DataOutputSerializer.resize(DataOutputSerializer.java:299)
    at org.apache.flink.core.memory.DataOutputSerializer.write(DataOutputSerializer.java:124)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.DataOutputViewStream.write(DataOutputViewStream.java:42)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.flush(Output.java:185)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.require(Output.java:164)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString_slow(Output.java:473)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString(Output.java:368)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:195)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:188)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:629)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:86)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.serialize(KryoSerializer.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamrecord.StreamElementSerializer.serialize(StreamElementSerializer.java:168)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamrecord.StreamElementSerializer.serialize(StreamElementSerializer.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.plugable.SerializationDelegate.write(SerializationDelegate.java:54)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.serializeRecord(RecordWriter.java:130)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.BroadcastRecordWriter.broadcastEmit(BroadcastRecordWriter.java:48)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.BroadcastRecordWriter.emit(BroadcastRecordWriter.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.pushToRecordWriter(RecordWriterOutput.java:101)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:87)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:43)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:107)
    -  locked java.lang.Object@11434500
    at xxx
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:263)
```

Any idea of why it could be? Could it be a slow loop in the serializing process? The data size is big but never had any problems previously.

The task did not fail but just loops around this point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're running low on heap space, and thus are "hung" in GC hell.